# Object area and maximum length of object

Tags: opencv, area

I'm a new user of open cv. I want to calculate the area of the object after labelling in the image. Then i need to find the maximum length of the object. (linearity = max length/Area * Pai/40)
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how did you label the image? based on your labeling, you may find some points describing that object contour. Therefore you may find its area using this [function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea):

```
double contourArea(InputArray contour, bool oriented=false )
```

And about the maximum length part, you may use this [function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect):

```
RotatedRect minAreaRect(InputArray points)
```

The length of the minimum-area bounding rectangle for your object, will give you the maximum length.

Anyway for this type of shape analysis you may take a look at the OpenCV documentation on [Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) as there are lots of more functions that may even help you more.